# How to add Show All and hide All in colvis code

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

i have this code from colvis. it work fine.

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#record_fpa1').DataTable( {
          "sDom": 'R<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    });
    var colvis = new $.fn.dataTable.ColVis( table );
    $( colvis.button() ).insertAfter('div.info');

});        
</script>
```

My problem is I want to add additional button inside above code for show all and hide all colvis data table but it not working. The code are below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
        columnDefs: [
            { visible: false, targets: 2 }
        ],
        colVis: {
            restore: "Restore",
            showAll: "Show all",
            showNone: "Show none"
        }
    });
});
```

how to combine below code to first code above?

```
colVis: {
    restore: "Restore",
    showAll: "Show all",
    showNone: "Show none"
}
```

Comment: sorry i use this with php code.. i delete the php tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the letter `C` in the  DOM of DataTable, this letter refers to show Colvis:

```
"sDom": 'CR<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/47/

Comment: wow.. i never know this.. thanks alot.. do you know any ways to make the colvis button outside the table using new initialisation method or sdom